# Merge files with the same name but different code - UNIX

Tags: unix, merge, concatenation

I would like to merge files which have the same part of the same:

```
XX_barcode2_XX.fastq
XX_barcode2_XX.fastq
XX_barcode3_XX.fastq
XX_barcode3_XX.fastq
XX_barcode4_XX.fastq
XX_barcode4_XX.fastq
```

So, I would like a file for barcode2, a file for barcode3 etc...

I was trying this:

```
for i in {2 .. 96};
do
   cat *_barcode$i*.fastq >> barcode$i.fastq;
done
```

but it does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Please define "does not work". Best to include a small amount of data  to illustrate your problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "file2 A" > XX_barcode2_XX.fastq
echo "file2 B" > XX_barcode2_YY.fastq
echo "file3 A" > XX_barcode3_XX.fastq
echo "file3 B" > XX_barcode3_YY.fastq
echo "file4 A" > XX_barcode4_XX.fastq
echo "file4 B" > XX_barcode4_YY.fastq

for i in {2..96}
do
    echo "i=$i"
    if find . -name "*_barcode$i*.fastq"
    then
        echo "in if"
        cat "*_barcode$i*.fastq" >> "barcode$i.fastq"
    fi
done
```

- the top of the script it just to create files for me to test with.
- the `if find ...` is to process only files that do exist.  Otherwise, it creates empty files form 5 to 96.  You can remove that if not required.
- you can remove the `echo` statements if you do not need debug messages.
- in your `for` loop, you had put spaces around the `{2 .. 96}`, bash is very particular about spaces in the wrong places.
- you can validate your syntax using https://www.shellcheck.net/ before posting.
- and `;` are not required to end lines, this is not C :)